# Passing the self parameter to a django callback

Tags: django, django-signals

I want to check if the model attributes make_initial_plan, make_default_plan going to be set in the model to be safe and if so to make unset all the attribute on all other model instances but I don't know how to pass the self parameter to the call back

```
@receiver(pre_save)
def desactivar_default_o_initial(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if self.make_initial_plan == True:
        for item in Plan.objects.all():
            item.make_initial_plan = False
            item.save(firstTimePass=False)
    if self.make_default_plan == True:
        for item in Plan.objects.all():
            item.make_default_plan = False
            item.save(firstTimePass=False)
```

Any Ideas, help in advance

Comment: The sender, and instance are from the LogEntry Objectt???

<class 'django.contrib.admin.models.LogEntry'>
LogEntry object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In signals there is no `self` because they are not class methods. You should use `sender` for getting class who sends the signal, and `instance` for the object itself (i.e. that's what you need here)

Also, I think you should provide a `sender` argument to signal connector. In current setup your handler will be used for any django model ever.